# how to process plenty of files by multi-thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, file-processing

Now I have plenty of JSON files on local, I need read these files and transfer them to JSONObject then do some business logical, such as find out the child-node then return, count some special value then return.

As the single file, I have finished the code of read the JSON file-->transfer it to JSONObject-->do the search of child-node/ count some special value.

But if when there was plenty of JSON files, how can I do this job?
I believe multi-thread could resolve my problem, but how can I collect every thread's result and finally get one result?

By the way, if I need create a thread pool and how ?

Comment: What is the problem when doing it sequentially, in a single thread? Start doing that first. There is a big chance it will be fast enough, or even faster than a multi-thread solution, given that you main bottleneck is disk IO, and multithreading won't improve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try multi-threading it using Streams. There is no guarantee this will be faster, or if your tasks use lots of memory, you could run out of memory but this is a simple way to try this.

```
List<Result> results= Files.list(path).parallel()
                           .map(p -> turnFileIntoJSONObject(p))
                           .map(json -> process(json))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will distribute the files to be processed across your available CPUs and collect the results at the end.

You can also drop the `.parallel()` if it is not faster for you.